# Independent & non independent effect sizes/correlations for meta analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, pearson-r

I am conducting a meta analysis of pearsons r correlations and would like to double check my understanding of independent and non- independent effect sizes/correlations. 
Am I correct in understanding that all effect sizes/correlations for meta analysis should be independent , as in a single effect size for each article/study , which means that any article presenting more than one effect/correlation related to the same construct being measured should ALWAYS be averaged into one effect size/correlation via converting the r correlations into fishers z scores for averaging and analysis?

Thanks

Comment: Further to this , I also have several effects/correlations for the criterion measure in some studies ( job performance of task , contextual , managerial). As my meta analysis investigates how sorting constructs into these performance domains affects the correlations , I am confused as to why I would average them if I need to keep them as separate?

Comment: See my answer to a related question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327186/meta-analyzing-dependent-effect-sizes-log-response-ratios-is-averaging-effect/327240#327240

Comment: thanks jsajaluk. I am interested in creating a single effect to represent the range of non -independent effects using sample size-weighted composite correlations , in following methods of previous author. Although the author does not explain exactly how they did this?