# Averaging Meta-Analytic Correlations?

Tags: meta-analysis

I am conducting meta-analytic SEM and interested in looking at one outcome. A previous meta I was going to use as part of my data reports meta-analytic correlations for this outcome, however it is pulled into two sub-categories. It is more common in recent literature to report one outcome. Can I just take an average of these two meta-analytic correlations or do I need to use a different approach in combining?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Dear Curious, welcome to a universe of other curious people! Perhaps you could add some details to help clarify the question. As I'm sure you know, one can average the *numbers* of red jelly beans in two jars, but one can't average the *proportions* of red jelly beans in two jars. Which kind of problem are you dealing with?

Comment: I think you are going to have to provide more detail here for anyone to try a response. What do you mean by a meta-analytic SEM? What are the meta-analytic correlations reported between? When you say average the correlations do you mean take their arithmetic mean, transform first, or meta-analyse them?

Comment: Explore the mvmeta R or Stata package. It should be able to pool correlated outcomes.

Comment: Welcome C M-A! If I understand your question correctly (I agree w/ @mdewey that more detail--and perhaps an example--could be helpful), you may find my response on this thread addresses your question about averaging the two correlations: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327186/meta-analyzing-dependent-effect-sizes-log-response-ratios-is-averaging-effect/327240#327240